# Need to find java version number using c++ program

Tags: visual-c++

I'm new to C++ programming. So, which libraries or functions should I use in retrieving this info from the registry? Just give me a brief idea about the steps involved in retrieving the java version number from registry. I'm using VC++.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did (or didn't) that work? Maybe you need to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). or how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Why do you search for the Java version when using C++? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If java paths are properly set, you could just run java -version from code:
Using the code described here [How to execute a command and get output of command within C++ using POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c) :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

std::string exec(char* cmd) {
    FILE* pipe = _popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    _pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

using like:

```
int main(void) {
    std::cout << exec("java -version");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).